# Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Procedure id_management, Line 13 Must declare the scalar variable "@COMBINE"

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

```
CREATE PROCEDURE id_management
AS 
BEGIN
  DECLARE @SDOW DATETIME
  DECLARE @COMBINE VARCHAR(300))
  SET @COMBINE = (CONCAT(DealerAddMrv.CreationDate,DealerAddHist.mnmUserType,DealerAddMrv.mnmUserStatus,DeletedDealerAddHist.DelSourceUserId,DeletedDealerAddMrv.DelDtTime As AppID_Status))
  SET @SDOW= (SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 2 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)))

PRINT @SDOW
 SELECT UserInOut.mnmUser as AppID_ID,DealerAddMrv.mnmRole as AppID_Type,DealerAddMrv.mnmUserName
 as AppID_Name,UserInOut.mnmUserAccessType as Access_Type,
 DealerAddMrv.mnmUserName as AppID_Implemented_By
,'IND' as Access_Country,UserInOut.DtTime as AppID_Implemented_TimeStamp,DealerAddMrv.mnmUserStatus As AppID_Status,@COMBINE FROM "dbo"."UserInOut" 
INNER JOIN "dbo"."DealerAddMrv"
on "DealerAddMrv"."mnmUser" = "UserInOut"."mnmUser" 
INNER JOIN "dbo"."DealerAddHist" 
on "DealerAddHist"."mnmUser" = "DealerAddMrv"."mnmUser"
INNER JOIN "dbo"."DeletedDealerAddHist" 
on "DeletedDealerAddHist"."DelSourceUserId" = "DeletedDealerAddMrv"."DelSourceUserId"
order by "UserInOut"."mnmUser"
where UserInOut.DtTime >= @SDOW
END
GO
```

Comment: Stored procedures are not part of standard SQL. You should [edit] your question and add a tag indicating which DBMS you are using. Is it SQL Server? Also, your question is not clear. Is your stored procedure failing compilation?

Comment: The code you have posted will not result in the error message in your title. It has errors much earlier than that. As JShark pointed out, it has an additional closing parenthesis on line 5. Also, the set statement on line 6 is invalid. You cant do `set @variable = concat(t1.column, t2.column, ...)` At the very least you need to fix your question to at least include the code actually causing the error.

Answer (score 1):

Is there an extra bracket after VARCHAR(300)